# Open Source Control Explorer programmatically

Tags: c#, vspackage, source-control-explorer

I want to open the Source Control Explorer tool window programmatically but I can't find any documentation.

```
ToolWindowPane window = this.FindToolWindow(typeof(**SourceControlExplorer**), 0, true);
if (null == window || null == window.Frame)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException("Not found");
}
```

Can someone tell me the type?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the SourceControlExplorer has a managed type definition. However, the toolwindow guid is defined in the Microsoft.VisualStudio namespace as:

[VSConstants.StandardToolWindows.SourceControlExplorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vsconstants.standardtoolwindows.sourcecontrolexplorer.aspx)

The Package method doesn't have an overload that takes a guid, but you can readily invoke the same functionality direction from the IVsUIShell interface as follows:

```
IVsUIShell vsShell = (IVsUIShell)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SVsUIShell));
Guid guidToolWindow = VSConstants.StandardToolWindows.SourceControlExplorer;
IVsWindowFrame pFrame = null;
vsShell.FindToolWindow(0, ref guidToolWindow, out pFrame);
if (pFrame!=null)
   pFrame.Show();
```

Sincerely,